# Can I make .net webbrowser display HTML form elements with window form native OS appearence?

Tags: c#, vb.net, webbrowser-control

Is possible to make the .Net Webbrowser control render form elements, like buttons, input text, with winform elements appearance? Using the visual styles of OS to look like an native Windows application not an page displayed in IE?

[image: Example]

Comment: Do you have more context to add?  Any code samples?  More information on what you are trying to do?  If you want to know if you can style a page and then display that page inside the web browser control (I am assuming you are doing this in WPF then...) then obviously you can but you need to try something before asking how to do it.

Comment: I want to show elements with OS theme (Win Xp, Windows 7, Vista) in regular C# or VB.net application, not WPF. [link](http://rttelas.com.br/render.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible configure or to supply custom rendering for buttons and input controls in IE - without CSS you get what browser decided to use as default.

It is possible to style buttons/input elements with CSS pretty much whatever way you want.

Comment: Not custom rendering, native OS (Windows) buttons, dropdowns etc. I know that is possible style elements with CSS.

Comment: But you can include a flag in your URL when you load the page in the webbrowser, and then use that flag to use CSS that styles as you need.

Answer (score 0):

I am not entirely sure what you want to get. Possible you can render the entire form as it is in the broswer. WPF let you embed winform in the browser:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/31429/Embedding-a-NET-WinForms-Application-in-an-Interne

Comment: No, I want display HTML form button with the same appearance of the buttons of Windows. like in vb.net or C# app.

Comment: No, I want to create an HTML with controls uses native user theme.

Comment: If default ones are doing any good to you, than custom CSS is the way. You can target platform / browser in your CSS. you might find this useful: http://rafael.adm.br/css_browser_selector/

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible as @Alexei Levenkov Informed.

But I recommend you to have look over [this link](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/67148/Web-Browser-with-C) where the web browser is created with C#.

[image: Web-Browser Screenshot]